# Using javascript validation in WordPress plugin development

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

Started developing custom database table plugin in WordPress.

When I started using jquery in my plugin, I have begun receiving notices errors like:

> wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly.

I need some help on how to call jQuery / js in WordPress plugin.

Here is my validation code:

```js
<script>
    var jq = $.noConflict();
    jq(document).ready(function(){
        jq('#submit').click( function() {

            //check whether browser fully supports all File API
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
            {

                //get the file size and file type from file input field
                var fsize = jq('#File_Upload')[0].files[0].size;

                if(fsize>5000000) //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
                {
                    //alert ("Only the file less than 5 mb  allowed to upload");
                    //alert ('<?php echo "Only the file less than 5 mb  allowed to upload";?>');
                    jq('.file-upload-error').show(0).delay(10000).hide(0);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code is used for upload validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have changed a little bit your javascript/jQuery code:

```css
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    console.log("plugin script loaded");
    $('#submit').click( function() {

        //check whether browser fully supports all File API
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
        {

            //get the file size and file type from file input field
            var fsize = $('#File_Upload')[0].files[0].size;

            if(fsize>5000000) //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
            {
                console.log("Only the file less than 5 mb  allowed to upload");
                $('.file-upload-error').show(0).delay(10000).hide(0);;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("file is less than 5 mb allowed to upload");
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the correct way for enqueuing a javascript file for a plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_table_example_validation' );
function custom_table_example_validation() {
    wp_register_script( 'est_collaboration', plugins_url('/js/upload_valid.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

This should work

Comment: Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url site for plugins_url().

Comment: @Loic No, its not working; I tried passing absolute path also...still its not calling js file.